# To open a new page and run a javascript function in that new page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi i am trying to open a new page using button click from page 1 and
in the page 2 i want to have a popup message using alert .
But the alert is executed in my page 1 itself.
Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong .

```
function sendemail(){
alert('success');
var popup = window.open();
window.onload = test();
function test(){
alert('new');
}
}
sndWelcomEmail.addEventListener('click',sendemail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply alert the new window not the old one:

```
function sendemail() {
    var popup = window.open();
    window.onload = test();
    function test() {
        popup.alert('new');
    }
}

sndWelcomEmail.addEventListener('click', sendemail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing, when you create a new window append a script tag in it. Create a test.js file and add that in.

```
var newWindow = window.open('');
newWindow.document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'js/sample.js';
newWindow.document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Or,

```
var newWindow = window.open('') // open a blank tab;
newWindow.document.write('<script>alert("Hello World!")</script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like websockets for that, sync user and sent data between pages, executing scripts from one page directly on another is prohibited, its pure xss.

Comment: It is prohibited when you are trying to execute that on any other page, he is trying to open the new or existing browsing context (window, <iframe> or tab) from his own page. You can check here for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it right now but try using

```
popup.onload = test()
```

imstead of

```
window.onload = test()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **page 2**

First, Add an **onload** function in body tag

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

Second, Add this JS Script

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is how does the page 2 knows that user is coming from page 1 and wants a popUp.
There are plenty of ways to solve this issues.

1. Add a hash value, which can be passed to page 2, using the address bar. (Page 2 looks at the hash value in the address bar, then does whats needed. EG.http:kdsjhf.com/#openAlert
2. Use more refined approach using pop-state and history object to pass data between navigating pages.
   3.PWA.