How to retrieve text value from a separate page after a calculation, using jQuery or JavaScript
I am attempting to retrieve two text values from a separate html page using jQuery. I have successfully achieved this for the first text value (#text1) using this code:
$(function(){
    $('#text1').load('page2.html #target1');
});

But I am struggling to get the same to work for the second text value (#text2), which is the result of a JS calculation that happens after page load on the separate page (counting a number of items). I thought this failure may be due to the delay, so I added a timeout function as follows:
$(document).ready(function() {

  function delay() {
    $('#text2').load('page2.html #target2');
  }

  setTimeout(delay, 1000)

});

But this was unsuccessful, so I suspect it may have something to do with the #target2 value being the result of a calculation and not being saved into the html. Is there another way I can retrieve this value? I should probably add that I am very new to jQuery and JavaScript.

To confirm: #target2 on page2 is only set after a delay - so you've added a delay before you call page2?  When page2 "loads" it will still have the same delay, it just doesn't load as soon due to your timeout on page1.   .load will load the page when it is called.  Not that $(..).load(page2) will not run any javascript on page2.   These answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212151/how-to-execute-javascript-writen-in-one-page-from-another-page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66417115/to-open-a-new-page-and-run-a-javascript-function-in-that-new-page
